# Create fragments, for older versions of android

Tags: android

How can I use fragments, in older versions of android.
For android HoneyComb and early I write this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        Fragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.topMenu, menuFragment).commit();

        Fragment contentFragment = new AlleFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, contentFragment).commit();   
    }
```

But I don't know how to write this code to run for older version of android.
Can someone to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include support library v4 which comes with Android SDK.  You have example in official Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html